# Why router passing query parameters with ";" in Angular8?

Tags: angular

How can I achieve this example of route navigation using router.navigate?

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`enrollment?id=${student.id}&request=${"delete"}`);
```

I've tried this `this.router.navigate(['enrollment',{id:student.id}]);` but it includes ";" character(/enrollment;id=n) and also how can I make it have multiple parameters/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass multiple parameters. [More info](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters)

```
path: 'enrollment/:id/:name'

this.router.navigate(['enrollment', {
  id: student.id,
  name: student.name
}]);
```

You can access it by

```
// import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
// private route: ActivatedRoute

this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

Comment: I can't get the parameter using `this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params =>
      this.studentId=params['id']);`